# Not able to get condition operators in EasyQuery

Tags: easyquery, bi-tool

I was exploring **EasyQuery** for our db requirements.
i downloaded the trial version and in samples i replaced my datamodel created using EasyQuery itself.
but when i run the sample project in condition panel where there is text to choose condition operator. **it displays text "Unrecognized Operator".**

can anybody help me out to find out what could be the problem. on site of easy query there is no detailed help about query conditions  panel.

any type of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your attribute has the empty list of operators for some reason.

The best you can do is to contact EasyQuery support - they are usually quick and responsive.
Send them your model to define where the problem is.